# AEROSPIKE_ERR = -1

Tags: php, aerospike

Интересует в большей степени чем вызывается ошибка AEROSPIKE_ERR = -1 (из-за чего при каких условиях), пути решения не так важны. Докер не используется.  Ошибка появляется редко, пытаюсь понять из-за чего. Небольшой код в котором (мне так кажется) эта ошибка может появляться

```
public function aeroDBGet($ns, $set, $bin, $primaryKey, $readtimeout = 2000, $retries = 5, $sleep_retries = 500) {

    

    $atimeout = $readtimeout;
    for ($attempts = 0; $attempts < 10; $attempts++) {
        if (!empty($set) && !empty($bin) && !empty($primaryKey)) {
            Logger::add_msg("INFO: DBF: [". FUNCTION . "]: attempt = " . $attempts);
            Logger::add_msg("INFO: DBF: [". FUNCTION . "]: set, bin, primaryKey not empty");

            $options = [
                \Aerospike::OPT_READ_TIMEOUT            => $atimeout,
                \Aerospike::OPT_MAX_RETRIES             => $retries,
                \Aerospike::OPT_SLEEP_BETWEEN_RETRIES   => $sleep_retries
            ];

            $key    = self::$adb->initKey($ns, $set, $primaryKey);
            $status = self::$adb->get($key, $answ_data,bin, $options); 
            if ($status == \Aerospike::OK) {
                // Все ок, прочитали
                //Logger::add_msg("INFO: DBF: [". FUNCTION . "]: все ок aeroget_v40");
                return var_dump($answ_data);
            } elseif ($status == \Aerospike::ERR_RECORD_NOT_FOUND) {
                // Запись не найдена
                Logger::add_msg("INFO: DBF: [". FUNCTION . "]: AeroStatusNotFound = " . $status);
                return false;
            } elseif ((self::$adb->errorno() == -1) OR (!self::$adb->isConnected())) {
                Logger::add_msg("INFO: DBF: [". FUNCTION . "]: AeroStatusMinusOne = " . $status);
                // Надо переподключиться
                self::$adb->reconnect();    
                $_db = AeroDBF::getInstance()->get_aero_reconnect();
                echo self::$adb->error() . " " . self::$adb->errorno();
            } else {
                // Не удалось прочитать
                Logger::add_msg("INFO: DBF: [". FUNCTION . "]: AeroStatusOther = " . $status);
                return false;
            }
            $atimeout = $atimeout + 2000;
        }
    }
}
```

Буду благодарен всем помогающим и сочувствующим.

Comment: "Unknown" or -1 is a bit overloaded, there will also be a warning in the logs associated with this error. Could you share the warning in your logs?

----

«Неизвестно» или -1 немного перегружено, в журналах также будет предупреждение, связанное с этой ошибкой. Не могли бы вы поделиться предупреждением в своих журналах?

Comment: @kporter К сожалению никаких записей нет, но я подозреваю второй вариант. Unfortunately, there are no records, but I suspect the second option.

Comment: If it happens again, there should be a `WARNING` message in `/var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log`. ---- 
Если это произойдет снова, в `/var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log` должно быть сообщение `WARNING`.

Comment: I would need to know what the warning is to help. ---- Мне нужно знать, какое предупреждение должно помочь.

Comment: @kporter Unfortunately, there is nothing in the logs. It turned out that logging was disabled in the aerospike config, because the number of actions either clogged the memory too quickly and loaded the system, or it was cleaned so quickly that it didn't make sense. the Error rarely appears when writing to the database. К сожалению, в логах нет ничего. Оказалось, что в конфиге aerospike логирование отключено, т.к. количество действий либо слишком быстро засоряло память и нагружало систему либо чистилось так быстро что не имело смысл. Ошибка появляется редко при записи в БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, спустя долгое время я узнал, что клиент PHP для aerospike выдает ошибку -1, когда теряет соединение с узлом базы данных и не успевает переподключиться, т.е. коннект пропал, PHP клиент пытается подключиться - ловит ошибку -1. Помогает ожидание в 1 секунду.

So, after a long time, I found out that the PHP client for aerospike gives an error -1 when it loses connection to the database node and does not have time to reconnect, I mean the connection is lost, the PHP client tries to connect - catches an error -1. Waiting for 1 second helps.